# How to find an element in a list of lists

Tags: java

I have the following list of lists `List<List<Integer>> dar = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`:

```
[[0], [1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [5, 0]]
```

I want to check whether the integer 5 is in any of the lists. If I use `if(dar.contains(5))`, it will return `false`.

What can I do to check whether an integer exists in any of the lists?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Iterate over the `List` of `List`'s and then call contains:

```
for(List<Integer> list : dar) {
    if(list.contains(5)) {
       //...
    }
}
```

Or use `Stream`s:

```
boolean five = dar.stream().flatMap(List::stream).anyMatch(e -> e == 5);
//Or:
boolean isFive = dar.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.contains(5));
```

Answer (score 5):

You have List of Lists. To search any value, you need nested loops.

```
public void contains(Integer x){
    for (int i= 0; i < dar.size(); i++){
        List<Integer> list = dar.get(i);
        for(int j= 0; j < list.size(); j++){
             if(x == list.get(j)) return true; //will handle both null cases
             if( x != null && x.equals(list.get(j)) return true;
        }
    }
}
```